# White bumps on goldfish

Tags: health, goldfish

I have 2 goldfish in a 20 gallon (76 liters) tank and last night I noticed one of them developed a white bump on its side, then this morning I noticed the other one has a similar white bump on its tail. Does anyone know what this is or what I can do to help? We cleaned the tank last week.

[image]

Comment: can you edit in the latest watertest,ammonia,nitrite,nitate,ph,do you have filtration and heat in your tank,is the tank properly cycled?